# How can I contact Facebook developers?

Tags: facebook

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to put this question.

I'm developing an application where I will be using Facebook data. Before that I want make my intentions clear to Facebook and ask some permissions for my app. I want to get in touch with them before they block my app. I tried googleing for the same but no luck. There is no direct contact even on https://developers.facebook.com/support/ or other related pages. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: There is one thing called as developer support - this is what I'm talking about - and that is also one of the things that product companies do.

Comment: facebook-size companies barely provide a direct communication with developers team. Even with subscription payments

Comment: find Mark Zuckerberg on facebook and send him a message regarding this issue :D

Comment: here is the link if you cant find him http://www.facebook.com/zuck

Comment: @Ushan87, funny that.

Comment: @zerkms, so do you mean to say that there is no way to contact Facebook Developers Team? I'm sure Microsoft bigger than Facebook and they do the direct communication, I did it many times and that is too without paying a penny

Comment: we work with these behemoths: Google, Amazon, Apple and Facebook.  I listed them in order of quality of support we're able to get when needed.  We're able to get direct support from all of them, except Facebook.  After 6 years, it remains a real problem.   PS... I get that this isn't a technical question. But I'm glad it's out here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go check this link

> https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/

seems like that they have shift their forum to

> http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Post here your question and hopefully a FB develoer will contact you. I wish you best of luck :)