# Facebook Permission For Use of Content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am hoping a Facebook developer will see this and get back to me. I am working on a science fair project and wondering if it would be ok to download some of my friends profile pictures so I can write a program that use it for facial recognition? I have realized that Facebook's API does not support this when I tried to use the Facebook Graph Explorer API, but I just wanted to know to make sure that I have Facebook's permission to do so.

Comment: This isn't the place to ask about this,  you should email Facebook directly and ask them

Comment: This isnt FaceBook, this is StackOverflow.

Comment: The thing is that their doesn't appear to be any means of contacting them. I got the idea of asking here from - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458044/how-can-i-contact-facebook-developers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Facebook Terms of Use question. Not a programming question.

Comment: And... aside from my close vote: Do not post here asking people to email you. That goes completely against the Q&A sharing intent of StackOverflow, asking people to email you privately. I removed your email address and related request from your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just ask your friends for their profile pictures, no need to ask Facebook for permission

Comment: 3.2. You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission. - (We apparently need to ask them for permission, but don't have any better means of doing so than stack overflow.)

Comment: @AkulGupta I'm not saying to get them from Facebook, just ask your friends for the photo. If they still have the photo they can send it to gou

Answer (score 2):

It´s very simple: do not use ANY data/media from anyone without authorization. That means, you can create an App, let your friends authorize it and then get the profile pictures of your friends. And you need to make sure everyone knows what you are doing with their data/media.

It´s not even just about Facebook, it´s a general data usage rule not to use anything from anyone without authorization.