# How to add additional permissions to live iOS app in production?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My existing iOS (native) app has basic readonly permissions, and is live & in production. Now I want to add the following roles for new features that have not been developed yet: `manage_pages publish_pages publish_actions`

It seems like a chicken-and-egg problem to me:

- In order to add the permissions, I have to supply an app to the Facebook Review team that has features working that use these permissions, so Facebook can test them
- In order to publish an update to this live app with the added features, I have to have the permissions approved by Facebook

How can this be done?

Comment: Better if you communicate facebook developer team.

Comment: @dahiya_boy how?

Answer (score 1):

I found group on with name **Facebook Developer Community**, what they have stated I mentioned in the below with screenshot image of there group description.

### **Screenshot :**

[image]

### **Text copy of Description :**

Welcome!  This is a forum for developers building on the Facebook platform to interact with the Facebook team and other developers.

For documentation and latest updates, visit the Facebook for Developers site: 
https://developers.facebook.com/

To report a Platform bug, please visit: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

To report an app for a policy violation, please visit: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/498927050438560

For detailed technical questions please use a programming Q&A site such as StackOverflow: 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com

If your app was restricted or removed from Facebook - you can learn more or appeal the restriction at:
https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

This group is not for asking questions about using Facebook or your profile, asking people to like your page or app, advertising your site, hiring or soliciting professional services, posting photos of yourself, etc.  Such posts will be removed and you may be removed from the group.

Please do not send unsolicited friend requests to the group admins.

Don't hesitate to ask a question otherwise but please search first to make sure that your question haven't been answered already - let's build!

### **Related question :**

Here is one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458044/how-can-i-contact-facebook-developers) which is related somehow to your app.

Hope these answers helps you. By the way before implementing wrong is better if you take consult with the facebook so that you have right path and vision.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned i applied to join this closed group and my application to it is pending.

Comment: @xaphod Yeah it is a closed group and as they are said there are facebook developers are available to help the other developer to integrate fb in a proper manner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be that you have to build the features into your app without the permission, ie. "simulate" it happening, record a video of your app "simulating" it, and post that video to facebook with details for the review.